# Display the table structured output for empty results of the queries mysql

Tags: mysql

I am executing a MySql query in MySql command prompt. And I have a MySQL query which returns an empty result set. When the result set is not empty, the results will be automatically displayed in a table structured manner.

[image: result set output]

But when the result set is empty, a message called `"Empty set"` will be displayed to the user.

I want the above shown table structure to be displayed even for empty result sets. How could I achieve this in MySQL?

Comment: I don't know how to do this, but why do you want to see table structure in the case of an empty result set?

Comment: This is a verification script at the production level. Just to be more descriptive and to indicate that the missing values are empty. This might be executed by the non-technical people and need a more descriptive message then

Comment: I actually prefer `empty result set` for the simple reason that, in the case of a MySQL table with many columns, an output which _does_ contain columns, with no data, might be hard to distinguish from, e.g., an output with a single record in it.